# возможно ли сделать несколько переборов списка в другом переборе

Tags: python

Суть в том, что я пытаюсь создавать файл, в котором будут генерироваться цены в пределах 50% от цены в другом файле , для замены цены в новом файле не нашел ничего умнее как просто воспользоваться replace, загвоздка в том что, как реализовать переборы, для нормальной построчной замены

```
    for element_new in finaly:
        element_new = str(element_new)

    for element_old in n2:
        element_old = str(element_old)

    for element in content:
        new_price = element.replace(element_old, element_new)
        file.write(new_price)
```

Comment: так построчно идите по двум файлам, из одного файла добавляйте в другой измененные данные

Answer (score 0):

Да, возможно. Но вам нужно не это.
Сделайте так:

```
for element_new, element_old, element in zip(finaly, n1, content):
    new_price = element.replace(element_old, element_new);
    file.write(new_price);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите сделать что-то такое, хотя это и будет очень неоптимально работать:

```
for element in content:
    new_price = element
    for element_new,element_old in zip(finaly,n2):
        element_new = str(element_new)
        element_old = str(element_old)
        new_price = new_price.replace(element_old, element_new)
    file.write(new_price)
```

Для того, чтобы советовать что-то более конкретное и оптимальное, надо смотреть на ваши данные.

Скорее всего там можно (и нужно) обойтись без `replace` и можно предварительно заполнить словарь, через который потом и заменять данные, это будет гораздо быстрее, чем вложенные циклы.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, я только начал изучать и моих знаний пока хватает только на  replace